# Cannot use matrix as function argument in maze-solver

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a maze from a .dat file given as command line argument. When printing the solution, the cells from the path should be represented by '.'. I know I defined the sizes of the matrix as macros, even though I have 2 functions to count the rows and columns, I did that to be able to use the sizes as parameters in functions (I have a possible solution for that in mind, but first I want to get this working in the current state). For reference:
`# - wall`, `S - starting point` , `E - end point`, `' ' - free cell`, `'.' - solution path`.
The maze in the .dat file:

```
################################################################################
#S                                                                  #          #
################################################################### # ######## #
#                                                           ####### # ##    ## #
# ######################################################### #       # ## ## ## #
# # #E                                                    # ####### # ## ## ## #
# # ##################################################### #         # ## #  ## #
# #                                                       ######### # ## ## ## #
# ####################################################### # #       # ## ## ## #
# #                                                         # ##### # ## ## ## #
# # ####################################################### # # ### # ## ## ## #
# # #        #########################                      # #     # ## ## ## #
# # # ######                         ######################## ##### # ## ## ## #
# # # ## ### ####################### # ##     ###     ##    ##    # # ## ## ## #
# # #  #     #                       #    ###     ###    ##    #### # ## ## ## #
# # ## ############################# # ############################ # ## ## ## #
# # ## #                        ###  #                            # # ## ## ## #
# # ## # ########### ############   ## ############################## ## ## ## #
# #    #           # #            ####                                #  ###   #
# ################ # ####### ######### ##############################   #### # #
#                # # #                                            # ########## #
######## ######### # ############################################## #          #
#                  #                                                  ### ######
################################################################################
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define MAX 1000
#define HEIGHT 24
#define WIDTH 81

void storeMaze(int N, int M, int matrix[N][M], FILE *fp);
int countLines(FILE *fp);
int countColumns(FILE *fp);
int find_path(int x, int y, int maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);
void printMaze(int maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]);


int start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y;




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format.\nCorrect format: %s maze_file.dat\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    FILE *fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb");


    if(!fin)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    int N = countLines(fin); // lines in the matrix
    rewind(fin);
    int M = countColumns(fin); // columns in the matrix
    rewind(fin);
//  printf("Lines: %d | Columns: %d\n", N, M);
    int maze[N][M];
//  int sol[N][M];
    storeMaze(N, M, maze, fin);
    if(find_path(start_x, start_y, maze) == true)
    {
        printMaze(maze);
    }
    else
        printf("No solution!\n");
//  printf("Lines: %d | Columns: %d\n", N, M);//24 81
    
    
    fclose(fin);


    return 0;
}


void storeMaze(int N, int M, int matrix[N][M], FILE *fp)
{
    int z=0, i;
    char buf[1000];


    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
    {
        for(i = 0; buf[i] != '\n' && z < N; i++)
        {
            if(buf[i] == '#')
            {
                matrix[z][i] = 0;
                putchar('#');
            }
            else if(buf[i] == ' ')
            {
                matrix[z][i] = 1;
                putchar(' ');
            }
            else if(buf[i] == 'S')
            {
                start_x = z;
                start_y = i;
                matrix[z][i] = 2;
                putchar('S');
            }
            else if(buf[i] == 'E')
            {
                end_x = z;
                end_y = i;
                matrix[z][i] = 3;
                putchar('E');
            }


            //printf("%d ", matrix[z][i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        z++;


    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("The starting point: (%d,%d)\n", start_x, start_y);
    printf("The end point: (%d,%d)\n", end_x, end_y);
}


int countLines(FILE *fp)
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int countColumns(FILE *fp)
{
    char c;
    int count = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int find_path(int x, int y, int maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH])
{
    // If x,y is outside maze, return false.
    if ( x < 0 || x > HEIGHT - 1 || y < 0 || y > WIDTH - 1 ) 
    return false;

    // If x,y is the goal, return true.
    if ( maze[y][x] == 3 ) // 'E' - end point 
    return true;

    // If x,y is not open, return false.
    if ( maze[y][x] != 1 && maze[y][x] != 2 ) 
    return false;

    // Mark x,y part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = '.';

    // If find_path North of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x, y - 1, maze) == true ) 
    return true;

    // If find_path East of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x + 1, y, maze) == true ) 
    return true;

    // If find_path South of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x, y + 1, maze) == true ) 
    return true;

    // If find_path West of x,y is true, return true.
    if ( find_path(x - 1, y, maze) == true ) 
    return true;

    // Unmark x,y as part of solution path.
    maze[y][x] = 0; // mark this as a wall

    return false;
}

void printMaze(int maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]) {


    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                    printf("%d ", maze[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

This is properly storing the maze from the file into the matrix, it gets the right coordinates for the start and the end.
I don't usually use matrices, so I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening. If I run the code, there's no seg fault or anything, just:

```
################################################################################
#S                                                                  #          #
################################################################### # ######## #
#                                                           ####### # ##    ## #
# ######################################################### #       # ## ## ## #
# # #E                                                    # ####### # ## ## ## #
# # ##################################################### #         # ## #  ## #
# #                                                       ######### # ## ## ## #
# ####################################################### # #       # ## ## ## #
# #                                                         # ##### # ## ## ## #
# # ####################################################### # # ### # ## ## ## #
# # #        #########################                      # #     # ## ## ## #
# # # ######                         ######################## ##### # ## ## ## #
# # # ## ### ####################### # ##     ###     ##    ##    # # ## ## ## #
# # #  #     #                       #    ###     ###    ##    #### # ## ## ## #
# # ## ############################# # ############################ # ## ## ## #
# # ## #                        ###  #                            # # ## ## ## #
# # ## # ########### ############   ## ############################## ## ## ## #
# #    #           # #            ####                                #  ###   #
# ################ # ####### ######### ##############################   #### # #
#                # # #                                            # ########## #
######## ######### # ############################################## #          #
#                  #                                                  ### ######
################################################################################

The starting point: (1,1)
The end point: (5,5)
No solution!
```

Any idea how I could solve this? Thank you, in advance!

Comment: `int maze[HEIGHT][WIDTH]` and `char maze[WIDTH][HEIGHT]` are two *very* different things.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, that must've slipped. I've updated the code and the post, I don't have any warnings now, but the output is the same, no solution :/

Comment: Now is the time for you to learn to use a debugger. If you refrain from this, insert some `printf()` at "interesting" places in your code to follow variables.

Comment: Always a good read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/